# php regex to find nested multiline cfml comments

Tags: php, regex, nested, comments, multiline

Using php, I would like to have a regex that matches nested AND multiline comments of the style that ColdFusion supports:

```
1. <!--- this is a single comment line --->

2. <!---
multiline
comment
--->

3. <!---
multiline <!--- nested --->
comment <!--- comment --->
--->
```

All three of these cases are single valid cfml comments. I have found many regexes that work for the first two cases, but not the third which is the real bear. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive PCRE regex with the `gs` options:

```
(?<comment><!---(?(?=<!---)\g<comment>|.)*?--->)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pP0kG4/3)

Breakdown (`x` mode):

```
(?<comment>         # define group "comment"
  <!---             # match a "<!---"
  (?(?=<!---)       # is the next sequence a "<!---"
    \g<comment>     #   yes: match a comment (recurse)
    |.              #   no: match a character
  )*?               # and repeat
  --->              # until a "--->"
)                   # close "comment" definition
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a recursive pattern:

```
<!---(?>[^<-]+|-(?!-->)|<(?!!---)|(?R))*--->
```

details:

```
<!---
(?>              # open an atomic group
    [^<-]+       #   all that is not a < or a -
  |              #  OR
    -(?!-->)     #   a - not followed by -->
  |              #  OR
    <(?!!---)    #   a < not followed by !---
  |              #  OR
    (?R)         #   recursion (repeat the whole pattern itself)
)*               # close the atomic group, repeat zero or more times
--->
```